# Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list (Component)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 20.04

This is what i got after trying to install brave browser on my ubuntu 20.04,

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
```

then I executed second command

```
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
```

and the third one

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
```

after this when i executed the fouth one

```
sudo apt update
```

this gives error

```
Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-release.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

surprising enough these all commands are from official brave website.
please help. I even can not update ubuntu or uninstall any packages.
the page wisited to install brave was the [official brave wesite](https://brave.com/)
when hitting download brave for linux it ridirects to [this page](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux).
The contents of the `sources.list` are there but not for `sources.list.d` because there is no such file in directory not even hidden.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

the contents for `etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-release.list` are

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-releases.s3.brave.com/stable main
```

Comment: Give me the URL for the instructions that you're following. Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-release.list`.

Comment: none of this seems to help, because i tried editing the file `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` but it is no use i can't figure out what is wrong with the file, everything seems to be perfect. nothing is there from brave browser.

Comment: it works (Thanks alot), but does this means that i cannot install brave on my system ? or can i try again to install brave on my system again?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 2):

You have...

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-releases.s3.brave.com/stable main
```

It should be...

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
                                                  _             _
```

**Note**: remember to remove the leading `#` that you added.

**Source**: https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux

Comment: You found it. .

Comment: @karel I do that once and a while :-)

Comment: I've been reviewing a lot of `Malformed entry (Component)` questions lately sorting out the duplicates. Usually it's something like `trusty` instead of `xenial` or a missing space character, but this one is a typo inside the URL string which I've never encountered before, so I'm not going to close vote this question. Instead I'm going to use this question as a duplicate link for other malformed entry (Component) URL string questions.

Comment: @karel OP must have manually typed in the **echo deb...** command instead of copy/pasting it.